# Python3 and pandas

Tags: ubuntu, pandas, python-3.2

I have checked some other SO answers and googled somewhat extensively and cannot seem to find someone who has asked/answered this:

I am running Ubuntu 12.04.
I have python2.7 and python3.2 installed.
(I ran sudo apt-get install python-numpy, python3-numpy, and similar with scipy).
I ran sudo apt-get install python-pandas.
It works perfectly fine with python2.7.
It does not import in python3.2
I then modified my $PYTHONPATH to have the directory where pandas was installed, full aware that this might create an issue:

```
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7
```

Now when I try to import, I get

```
>>> import pandas
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pandas/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
import pandas.lib as lib
ImportError: /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pandas/lib.so: undefined symbol: _Py_ZeroStruct
```

So I've obviously missed something here. As a note, since I've just been doing all these python installations myself, and am still learning, my $PYTHONPATH may need updating; right now the only thing in it is the directory mentioned above. Are there other directories I should have in there, standardly?

(If you need any more information about my system, etc., please just comment.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Update

As mentioned below, pandas is now available for python 3.3, 3.4 and 3.5
[source](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/install.html)

For system wide install use:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pandas
```

### Original:

If this information http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/python/ is correct there is no pandas package for Python 3. You can install current pandas using virtualenv:

```
apt-get install python-virtualenv virtualenvwrapper

mkvirtualenv -p python3 pandas_env
pip install pandas
```

Generally it is a good idea to create separate virtual environments when working with Python and to avoid manual messing with system wide packages.

Comment: Hm, apt-get worked just fine, but it doesn't recognize mkvirtualenv as a command.

Comment: There's no virtualenvwrapper.sh in /usr/local/bin (or in /usr/bin, either)

Comment: Not familiar with virtualenvwrapper, but this should work:

    sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv python3-dev ,
    virtualenv -p python3 pandas_env ,
    pandas_env/bin/pip install pandas ,
    pandas_env/bin/python3 ,
    import pandas

Answer (score 3):

there is a python3-pip which will install pip-3.3 instead of pip. the pip-3.3 will install the pandas package into python3.3

Answer (score 3):

You may just install it by `sudo apt-get install python3-pandas` if you'd prefer a system-wide installation

Answer (score 0):

I use MacOSx and I manage to install it using:

```
brew install python3
sudo pip3 install --upgrade pip
pip3 install pandas
```

Check the installation using:

```
$python3
>>>import pandas as pd
>>>exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3-pip
sudo pip3 install pandas
```

Answer (score -1):

I would highly recommend that you install, and learn how to use, Anaconda to manage your python environments.It is superior to using pip, or virtualenv, pyenv or any of the wrappers for that stuff. Check it out:

https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/

Comment: By now - I only use this option