# ImportError: No module named 'pandas.indexes' in ubuntu

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, ubuntu

I get `ImportError: No module named 'pandas.indexes'` when I run my script (ubuntu 14.04.5, Linux 3.13.0-95-generic)

When I try to update pandas, as suggest in 
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18926696/python3-and-pandas) and [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37371451/importerror-no-module-named-pandas-indexes),
running
`pip3.4 install --upgrade pandas` or `python3.4 -m pip install --upgrade pandas`
I get a huge output, that has many warnings like
`#warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " \`

(I am not using anaconda)

Thanks for help.

Comment: I'd recommend you to install Anaconda, but install it locally - don't overwrite the system one

Comment: I had this same error in pandas version 0.19.2. I then upgraded to 0.20.2, re-ran the same code and no errors or problems.